# Custom keras loss function which contains a function of the outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm working on a specific problem and I need to implement a very particular loss function. Here some explanation : assuming that I have some snapshots called [image], each column of [image] corresponds to a snapshot.
And some modes called [image]. Each column of [image] corresponds to a mode.

My neural network takes some inputs [image] and gives N outputs say [image].

The custom loss function I want to implement in Keras is the following :

[image]

Such that  [image], and [image]

Finally, the problem can be seen as

1. For each column of [image], i.e. each snapshot, some sensors are also measured, i.e. [image]
2. with a measure sensor [image], rebuild a snapshot as [image]
3. the goal of the algorithm, is to find the best neural network [image] such that [image] 
   is close to [image]

---

Actually I've got something like :

```
def customLoss(modes,snap):
    def diff(y_true,y_pred):
        predField=modes[:,0]*y_pred[...,0]
        for ii in range(1,modes.shape[1]):
            predField+=modes[:,ii]*y_pred[...,ii]

        realData=#I don t know how can I extract from snap the correct columns

        return K.sum(K.square(predField-realData))

    return diff
```

Some dummies datas look like :

```
m=100
n=10000
N=30
ns=8

snap=np.random.rand((m,n))
modes=np.random.rand((m,N))
x=np.random.rand((ns,n))
```

Do you have any ideas how can I implement this?

Thanks
Charles

Comment: What is the dimension of `u` and each `g_i(x)`? what have you got so far?

Comment: I added some details into the question

Comment: Are you substracting `u_mxn` with `g_i(x)phi_i(x)_m`? what is your expected behavior?  your attempting to substract from each row in `u` the relevant `g_i(x)phi_i(x)_m`? isnt the first of shape `n` and the second of shape `m`?

Comment: The exepted behavior is to subtract the kth column of `u` which is a vector of size `m`, the sum on i of `g_i(x)phi_i(x)` which has the correct size.

Comment: If `n > N`, are you ignoring the columns from `u` which are not in `phi`?

Comment: `u` are snapshots, while `phi` are modes, see my original question, I added details

Comment: Just to get the notation right - When you say columns, you mean the `m` dimension, or the `n`?

Comment: `np.random.rand((n,m))` has `n` rows and `m` column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184759/discussion-between-dinari-and-charles).

Answer (score 0):

Hope i got your dimensions right -

```
def customLoss(modes, snap):
    modesT = K.transpose(modes) #We want to switch row-columns
    snapT = K.transpose(snap) # As y_pred is Nx1.

    def diff(y_true, y_pred):
        predFields = modesT * y_pred #This will result in Nxm, where each row is g_i(x_i)phi_i(x_i)
        return K.sum(K.square(snapT - predFields))
    return diff
```

As prediction return in shape `(Batchsize, features)` , and Keras plays well with rows for sample, and not columns, you need to swap the dimensions of both `mean` and `snap`.

After doing that, and executing the `predFields` line in the function, you will have the following:

- `snapT` : of shape `(N,m)`
- `predFields` :of shape `(N,m)`, where each row `i` corresponds to `g_i(x)phi_i(x)`.

Since both matrices are of the same shape, its simple subtracting between them, and each row from `snapT` will be substracted by the correct row from `predFields`. 

Note that I have made the assumption that each `column i` from `snap` "belongs" to sample `i` from the prediction.
Here is some toy example, where i tested this setting:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def customLoss(modes, snap):
    modesT = K.transpose(modes) #We want to switch row-columns
    snapT = K.transpose(snap) # As y_pred is Nx1.

    def diff(y_true, y_pred):
        predFields = modesT * y_pred #This will result in Nxm, where each row is g_i(x_i)phi_i(x_i)
        return K.sum(K.square(snapT - predFields))
    return diff

m = 3
N = 9

snapshot = np.random.randint(0,100, size =(m,N))
modes = np.random.randint(1,10, size = (m,N))

ytrue = np.arange(0,N).reshape((-1,1))
ypred = np.arange(0,N).reshape((-1,1))

loss = customLoss(modes,snapshot)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = loss(ytrue,ypred)
    print (sess.run(x))
```

If i still haven't got what you wanted right, some sample input and output could help.

Comment: You almost got it right, just `snapshots=np.random.rand((Ngrid,Ntime))`, `modes=np.random.ran((Ngrid,Nmodes))` and the input is somethng like `X=np.random.random((Nsensors,Ntime))`

Comment: With `Ntime` >> `Nmodes`

Comment: See my original question for more details about datas